# Failed to compile - Raspberry pi 4

Tags: android-source, raspberry-pi4

According to this instruction tried to compile android automotive for raspberry pi 4.
https://github.com/grapeup/aaos_local_manifest

After `. build/envsetup.sh` , when lunch command is given, getting error as follows:

```
che7@che7-w30984:~/aosp_raspberry$ lunch

You're building on Linux

Warning: Cannot display lunch menu.

Note: You can invoke lunch with an explicit target:

  usage: lunch [target]

Which would you like? [aosp_arm-eng]
Pick from common choices above (e.g. 13) or specify your own (e.g. aosp_barbet-eng): 13

**Failed to compile android/soong/cmd/soong_ui**: "/home/che7/aosp_raspberry/prebuilts/go/linux-x86/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/compile -N -l -o /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/out/.soong_ui_intermediates/android-soong-ui-build/android/soong/ui/build.a -p android/soong/ui/build -complete -pack -nolocalimports -c 20 -trimpath /home/che7/aosp_raspberry -I /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/out/.soong_ui_intermediates/android-soong-bazel -I /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/out/.soong_ui_intermediates/android-soong-finder -I /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/out/.soong_ui_intermediates/android-soong-finder-fs -I /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/out/.soong_ui_intermediates/android-soong-shared -I /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/out/.soong_ui_intermediates/android-soong-ui-build-paths -I /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/out/.soong_ui_intermediates/android-soong-ui-logger -I /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/out/.soong_ui_intermediates/android-soong-ui-metrics -I /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/out/.soong_ui_intermediates/android-soong-ui-metrics-metrics_proto -I /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/out/.soong_ui_intermediates/android-soong-ui-metrics-upload_proto -I /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/out/.soong_ui_intermediates/android-soong-ui-status -I /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/out/.soong_ui_intermediates/android-soong-ui-tracer -I /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/out/.soong_ui_intermediates/github.com-google-blueprint -I /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/out/.soong_ui_intermediates/github.com-google-blueprint-bootstrap -I /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/out/.soong_ui_intermediates/github.com-google-blueprint-deptools -I /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/out/.soong_ui_intermediates/github.com-google-blueprint-microfactory -I /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/out/.soong_ui_intermediates/google.golang.org-protobuf-proto /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/build/soong/ui/build/bazel.go /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/build/soong/ui/build/build.go /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/build/soong/ui/build/cleanbuild.go /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/build/soong/ui/build/config.go /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/build/soong/ui/build/config_linux.go /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/build/soong/ui/build/context.go /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/build/soong/ui/build/dumpvars.go /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/build/soong/ui/build/environment.go /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/build/soong/ui/build/exec.go /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/build/soong/ui/build/finder.go /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/build/soong/ui/build/goma.go /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/build/soong/ui/build/kati.go /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/build/soong/ui/build/ninja.go /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/build/soong/ui/build/path.go /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/build/soong/ui/build/proc_sync.go /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/build/soong/ui/build/rbe.go /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/build/soong/ui/build/sandbox_config.go /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/build/soong/ui/build/sandbox_linux.go /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/build/soong/ui/build/soong.go /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/build/soong/ui/build/test_build.go /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/build/soong/ui/build/upload.go /home/che7/aosp_raspberry/build/soong/ui/build/util.go": exit status 2
exit status 1
```

Build is failing with lunch target itself
Please suggest any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the version mismatch between the grapeup repo and the vanilla android repo that it is based on.
Some components from vanilla are pulled from latest version.
So grapeup is at 13_38 but Vanilla is at 13_56 or greater.
Update your local manifest to point to the correct version and the issue gets solved.
My manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <remote name="github" fetch="https://github.com/" />

  <!-- Raspberry Pi -->
  <project path="device/brcm/rpi4" name="grapeup/aaos_device_brcm_rpi4" remote="github" revision="android-13.0" >
    <linkfile src="mkimg.sh" dest="rpi4-mkimg.sh" />
  </project>
    <project path="device/brcm/rpi4-kernel" name="raspberry-vanilla/android_device_brcm_rpi4-kernel" remote="github" revision="android-13.0" />
  <project path="vendor/brcm" name="raspberry-vanilla/proprietary_vendor_brcm" remote="github" revision="android-13.0" />

  <!-- Automotive -->
  <project path="device/brcm/rpi4-car" name="grapeup/aaos_device_brcm_rpi4_car" remote="github" revision="android-13.0" />
  <project path="packages/apps/Car/AOSPHost" name="grapeup/aaos_car_aosp_host" remote="github" revision="android-13.0" />

  <!-- Audio -->
  <project path="external/alsa-lib" name="raspberry-vanilla/android_external_alsa-lib" remote="github" revision="android-13.0" />
  <project path="external/alsa-utils" name="raspberry-vanilla/android_external_alsa-utils" remote="github" revision="android-13.0" />

  <!-- Bluetooth -->
  <remove-project name="platform/hardware/interfaces" />
  <project path="hardware/interfaces" name="grapeup/aaos_android_hardware_interfaces" remote="github" revision="android-13.0" />

  <!-- Build -->
  <remove-project name="platform/build" />
  <remove-project name="platform/build/soong" />
  <project path="build/make" name="raspberry-vanilla/android_build" remote="github" revision="android-13.0" >
    <linkfile src="CleanSpec.mk" dest="build/CleanSpec.mk" />
    <linkfile src="buildspec.mk.default" dest="build/buildspec.mk.default" />
    <linkfile src="core" dest="build/core" />
    <linkfile src="envsetup.sh" dest="build/envsetup.sh" />
    <linkfile src="target" dest="build/target" />
    <linkfile src="tools" dest="build/tools" />
  </project>
  <project path="build/soong" name="raspberry-vanilla/android_build_soong" remote="github" revision="android-13.0.0_r35" >
    <linkfile src="root.bp" dest="Android.bp" />
    <linkfile src="bootstrap.bash" dest="bootstrap.bash" />
  </project>

  <!-- Camera -->
  <project path="external/libcamera" name="raspberry-vanilla/android_external_libcamera" remote="github" revision="android-13.0" />
  <project path="external/libyaml" name="raspberry-vanilla/android_external_libyaml" remote="github" revision="android-13.0" />
  <project path="external/libyuv_chromium" name="raspberry-vanilla/android_external_libyuv_chromium" remote="github" revision="android-13.0" />

  <!-- FFmpeg -->
  <project path="external/dav1d"  name="raspberry-vanilla/android_external_dav1d"  remote="github" revision="android-13.0" />
  <project path="external/ffmpeg" name="raspberry-vanilla/android_external_ffmpeg" remote="github" revision="android-13.0" />
  <project path="external/ffmpeg_codec2" name="raspberry-vanilla/android_external_ffmpeg_codec2" remote="github" revision="android-13.0" />
  <project path="external/libudev-zero" name="raspberry-vanilla/android_external_libudev-zero" remote="github" revision="android-13.0" />

  <!-- Graphics -->
  <remove-project name="platform/external/drm_hwcomposer" />
  <remove-project name="platform/external/libdrm" />
  <remove-project name="platform/external/mesa3d" />
  <remove-project name="platform/external/minigbm" />
  <project path="external/drm_hwcomposer" name="raspberry-vanilla/android_external_drm_hwcomposer" remote="github" revision="android-13.0" />
  <project path="external/libdrm" name="raspberry-vanilla/android_external_libdrm" remote="github" revision="android-13.0" />
  <project path="external/mesa3d" name="raspberry-vanilla/android_external_mesa3d" remote="github" revision="android-13.0" />
  <project path="external/minigbm" name="raspberry-vanilla/android_external_minigbm" remote="github" revision="android-13.0" />

  <!-- v4l2_codec2 -->
  <remove-project name="platform/external/v4l2_codec2" />
  <project path="external/v4l2_codec2" name="raspberry-vanilla/android_external_v4l2_codec2" remote="github" revision="android-13.0" />

  <!-- Wifi -->
  <remove-project name="platform/packages/modules/Wifi" />
  <project path="packages/modules/Wifi" name="raspberry-vanilla/android_packages_modules_Wifi" remote="github" revision="android-13.0" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please be sure to either convert this post into a comment when you get commenting privilege, or to turn it into a qualified answer (see [answer] for guidance)

Answer (score -1):

It appears you're encountering a compilation error when setting up Android Automotive for Raspberry Pi 4 using the instructions from the Grapeup AAOS local manifest. From my research and experience in resolving similar issues, the problem seems to stem from mismatches in the versions of remote repositories in the repo. To address this, you can make specific modifications in the manifest_brcm_rpi4.xml file. If you've already cloned the repositories, this file should be located in .repo/local_manifests.

Here are the steps you can follow to resolve the issue:

1. Modify Build Projects in the Manifest: You need to update the revision values for the raspberry-vanilla/android_build and raspberry-vanilla/android_build_soong projects in your manifest_brcm_rpi4.xml file. Change their revision values from android-13.0 to android-13.0.0_r35. This modification ensures that your build system uses the correct version of these components compatible with Android 13.0.0 Release 35.

Here's how you can modify it:

```
<project path="build/make" name="raspberry-vanilla/android_build" remote="github" revision="android-13.0.0_r35" >
  <!-- ... other settings ... -->
</project>
<project path="build/soong" name="raspberry-vanilla/android_build_soong" remote="github" revision="android-13.0.0_r35" >
  <!-- ... other settings ... -->
</project>
```

2. Update FFmpeg Project: Similarly, update the revision value for the raspberry-vanilla/android_external_ffmpeg. Change revision values from android-13.0 to android-13.0-5.1.

```
<project path="external/ffmpeg" name="raspberry-vanilla/android_external_ffmpeg" remote="github" revision="android-13.0-5.1" />
```

After making these changes, try 'repo sync' again
I recommend you delete and recreate the project directory before 'repo sync'